# ASP.NET MVC submitting form on checkbox click

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

Is there anything special I should be doing in ASP.NET when I want to submit a form when a checkbox is clicked. This is some sample HTML I am using...

```
<form method="post" action="#">
                <input id="hi" class="hidden-field" type="checkbox" value="true" onclick="this.form.submit();" name="hi">hi</input>
            </form>
```

I tested this in JSFiddle and when you click the checkbox, it naturally posts the form. Somehow I can't get this working inside a MVC PartialView.

Comment: If it works in jsFiddle but not in your MVC view, what's different about the two?  Does the `input` in your MVC view have a parent `form`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Javascript/jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#hi", function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

All you need is to bind a function on the click event, and in that function, call submit() manually.

Comment: Thank you. Although this wasn't the exact answer it let me to figure out the solution. I was using the Foundation responsive framework and apparently the checkboxes in their form framework respond to 'onchange' not 'onclick'.

Comment: Glad it is helpful to you.

Comment: You forgot a close bracket on the if. But otherwise, this has helped me, thanks very much!